# How do I make a random number shared between instances?

Tags: python, function, random

```
import random

class Unique_Key(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.uni_k =random.randint(1, 1000000)
    


unique_key_obj1=Unique_Key()
print(f"First Record {unique_key_obj1.uni_k}")


unique_key_obj=Unique_Key()
print(f"Second Record {unique_key_obj.uni_k}")
```

Can someone please help me  with how to make the value of the `unique_key_obj1` object to be the same as that of the `unique_key_obj` object? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should set this variable as a *class variable* rather than an *instance variable*. Like so:

```
import random

class Unique_Key(object):
    uni_k = random.randint(1, 1000000)
    
    def __init__(self):
        pass

unique_key_obj1 = Unique_Key()
print(f"First Record {unique_key_obj1.uni_k}")

unique_key_obj = Unique_Key()
print(f"Second Record {unique_key_obj.uni_k}")
```

```
First Record 208217
Second Record 208217
```

When you set `self.some_variable` to a random value, it will create a variable that is specific to this instance only, and not shared between all instances of an object.

Class variables are typically defined outside of all the methods, placed right below the class header and before the constructor method and other methods.

Comment: Thank you so much, Nicolas Gervais. It worked just as I want it and thanks for the extra tuition too!

Answer (score 0):

Use Seeding the random generator.

```
import random

class Unique_Key(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.uni_k =random.randint(1, 1000000)
    
mySeed = random.randint(1, 1000000)
random.seed(mySeed)
unique_key_obj1=Unique_Key()
print(f"First Record {unique_key_obj1.uni_k}")


random.seed(mySeed)
unique_key_obj=Unique_Key()
print(f"Second Record {unique_key_obj.uni_k}")
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Rupesh. It did work but I don't want the two values to remain constant, I still want them to have random features but the same value.

Comment: I have edited my answer accordingly. You can just make Seed  a new random number
@agbesi-innocent

Answer (score 0):

you can doit without setting the `seed`. we can doit by saving the previous random state and assign it to the next random call. this will ensure generating the same numbers.

This have been taken from python docs.

**`random.getstate()`**

> Return an object capturing the current internal state of the
> generator. This object can be passed to setstate() to restore the
> state.

read more about random module in python docs [random](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html)

```
import random
prev_state = random.getstate()
num1 = random.randint(1, 1000000)

random.setstate(prev_state)
num2 = random.randint(1, 1000000)

print num1==num2
```

**output**

```
True
```

Now in your case you can save the state in the class object and not in the instance, see below. so in each new class instance you get the same random number.

```
class Unique_Key(object):
    intial_random_state = prev_state = random.getstate()

    def __init__(self):
        random.setstate(Unique_Key.intial_random_state)
        self.uni_k =random.randint(1, 1000000)

x = Unique_Key()
y = Unique_Key()
```

**output**

```
print x.uni_k == y.uni_k
True
```